# Unable to get value using @Value("${database.name}") from properties file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, properties-file

```java
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Value("${database.name}")
    private String dbname;

    public String dbname2;

    public Config(){
        dbname2 = dbname;
        System.out.println(" ::::: Got Data from properties file Successfully ::::: " + dbname2);
    }
}
```

```java
@Service
public class MainService {

    @Autowired
    Config config;

    public String getPropertiesData(){

        String data = "Properties Data is " + config.dbname2;

        return data;
    }
}
```

data in **application.properties** file:

```
server.port=8081
database.name=azurecosmosDB
```

**Stack Trace** is Below when starting the application:

```
 .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.0.RELEASE)

2019-11-06 13:10:21.106  INFO 13328 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication on LP-5CD921DY4D with PID 13328 (C:\Users\BalajiChe\Desktop\STOMP\demo\target\classes started by BalajiChe in C:\Users\BalajiChe\Desktop\STOMP\demo)
2019-11-06 13:10:21.113  INFO 13328 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-11-06 13:10:21.247  INFO 13328 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2019-11-06 13:10:21.247  INFO 13328 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2019-11-06 13:10:27.732  INFO 13328 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8081 (http)
2019-11-06 13:10:27.763  INFO 13328 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-11-06 13:10:27.763  INFO 13328 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.27]
2019-11-06 13:10:28.335  INFO 13328 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-11-06 13:10:28.336  INFO 13328 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 7089 ms
 ::::: Got Data from properties file Successfully ::::: null
2019-11-06 13:10:30.395  INFO 13328 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 2 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2019-11-06 13:10:31.212  INFO 13328 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-11-06 13:10:31.382  INFO 13328 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2019-11-06 13:10:32.063  INFO 13328 --- [  restartedMain] d.s.w.p.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper : Context refreshed
2019-11-06 13:10:32.128  INFO 13328 --- [  restartedMain] d.s.w.p.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper : Found 1 custom documentation plugin(s)
2019-11-06 13:10:32.168  INFO 13328 --- [  restartedMain] s.d.s.w.s.ApiListingReferenceScanner     : Scanning for api listing references
2019-11-06 13:10:32.523  INFO 13328 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8081 (http) with context path ''
2019-11-06 13:10:32.529  INFO 13328 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 12.299 seconds (JVM running for 14.621)
```

**Additionally,** Get Data from properties to file Successfully ::::: null ---- is coming in a console. have to get value from properties file while starting the application. Is there any way to get the value?

Comment: The value will be set AFTER the invocation of the constructor, so trying to print it in the constructor will always lead to `null`.

Comment: You could also add another property for that value. Since there are two fields, do they really mean the same? Then it should probably be one field, otherwise it should probably be to different properties with the same value...

Comment: Thanks for the comments M. Deinum &  dertoni . I really learned few concepts here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because in `Spring` the fields are initialized after the default constructor call, therefore you should only access it after the constructor is called, try this:

```
 @PostConstruct
 public void postConstructorMethod(){
    dbname2 = dbname;
    System.out.println(" ::::: Got Data from properties file Successfully ::::: " + dbname2);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Mustahsan . This really helped in my case. My original requirement is to create a Cosmos DB connection while starting up the application and passing that connection to different service classes through @Autowired. So, I posted a sample case here where I was facing issue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Balaji211 if this solved your problem you can consider accepting this answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 3):

As @Mustahsan says, you can't access a value injected into a field in the constructor, since the injection takes place after construction.

However, if you want to use a constructor, then instead of field injection you can use constructor injection which is generally considered better practice anyway:

```
@Configuration
public class Config {
    public String dbname2;

    public Config(@Value("${database.name}") String dbname){
        dbname2 = dbname;
        System.out.println(" ::::: Got Data from properties file Successfully ::::: " + dbname2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sidenote first:

Spring boot can read `application.properties` automatically only if put in

- `src/main/resources`
- `src/main/resources/config` folder

Make sure its there indeed.

**Now the real issue:**

You're trying to access the property **inside the constructor** and this is not how spring works:

Spring creates the object first (by calling its constructor) and only after that injects its fields.

So you have two ways:

**Option 1:**

Use constructor Injection for your beans (I see that you use `@Configuration` but this advice is more suitable for real beans, just makes more sense there):

```
@Component
class MyClass {

  public MyClass(@Value({"db.name"} String dbName) {
  ....
  }
}
```

**Option 2:**

Check not in constructor but in postconstruct or if you're talking about configurations in `@Bean` annotated methods:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {

     @Value("${db.name}")
     private String dbName;


     @Bean
     public SomeBean someBean() {
         // here dbName should be accessible
         return new SomeBean (dbName)
     }  

     // alternatively you can inject dbName like this:

     @Bean
     public SomeOtherBean someOtherBean(@Value("${db.name}") String dbName) {
         return new SomeOtherBean(dbName);
     }
}
```

Comment: Well thats not entirely correct... Properties can be in a variety of places, not only in src/main/resources... see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config

Comment: Yes, of course, you're right. I meant the "application.properties" not in tests and defaults that are widespread. Of course anything but the default requires the additional configuration...